Django admin site not loading in localhost
I am running python manage.py runserver on my django project but my django admin site is not loading locally. The URLs on http://127.0.0.1:8000/ are not functional. I am using Django==4.2.11 and Python 3.9
This is my urls.py
from django.contrib import admin

---

from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("api/", include(("api.urls", "api"), namespace="v1")),
]

and my settings.py
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "django.contrib.sites",
    "api",
    "authentication",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
    "simple_history.middleware.HistoryRequestMiddleware",
]

SITE_ID = 1

I don't know where else to look.

you get admin site http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin not at http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Yes, this was the issue. Thank you

Also, there was a setting on the application that was trying to connect to an external storage server that I was unaware of. My bad
